# swarrow in linear equations

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows, arrows

I would like to write in LateX two equations, in which they are related by a sort of arrows (like the photo shows), and i don't know how to do it. How can i do it? i always get a very big space between the variables. Thank you. here is my code that i am using:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.5pt]
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}(1+&24x\arrow[ld]+&324x^2\arrow[ld]+&3200x^3\arrow[ld]+&25650x^4\arrow[ld]+&176256x^5+&O(x^6))  \\
f(x)={\sqrt(x)}(1+&24x+&324x^2+&3200x^3+&25650x^4+&176256x^5+&O(x^6))
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you set on using `tikz-cd`? Maybe a normal `align` and `tikzmarknode` would be better. Though, with the right settings you could do this with `tikz-cd`, too.

Comment: On a side note, please read the basic rules of this website where you would learn that it's better to ask a question by providing a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: By the way, it should be `\sqrt{x}` not `\sqrt(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick setup to give you the hint on how to do this with `tikzmark` library.
Of course, you can include this in an `align` environment as well.

[image: arrows in linear equations]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\tmn}{\tikzmarknode}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every node/.style={outer sep=2pt}}

\[
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}(1+\tmn{A}{24x}+\tmn{B}{324x^2}+\tmn{C}{3200x^3}+\tmn{D}{25650x^4}+\tmn{E}{176256x^5}+O(x^6))  \]
\[f(x)={\sqrt(x)}(\tmn{a}{1}+\tmn{b}{24x}+\tmn{c}{324x^2}+\tmn{d}{3200x^3}+\tmn{e}{25650x^4}+176256x^5+O(x^6))
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>={Stealth[scale=1.2]}]
    \foreach \L/\l in {A/a,B/b,C/c,D/d,E/e}
        \draw [->] (\L) -- (\l);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is absolutely not optimized, as you can see that each arrow doesn't lie on the same level, according to the different heights of simple terms and powered terms. This is customizable but you get the idea.

### EDIT

Here's a version where some `vphantom`s have been added to correct the misalignment of arrow tips, and to avoid those arrows to be aligned (by default) with node centers, I corrected their anchors.

[image: version 2]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc, arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\tmn}{\tikzmarknode}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every node/.style={outer sep=1pt}}

\[
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}(1+\tmn{A}{24x}+\tmn{B}{324x^2}+\tmn{C}{3200x^3}+\tmn{D}{25650x^4}+\tmn{E}{176256x^5}+O(x^6))  \]
\[f(x)={\sqrt(x)}(\tmn{a}{\vphantom{x^2}1}+\tmn{b}{\vphantom{x^2}24x}+\tmn{c}{324x^2}+\tmn{d}{3200x^3}+\tmn{e}{25650x^4}+176256x^5+O(x^6))
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>={Stealth[scale=1.2]}]
    \foreach \L/\l in {A/a,B/b,C/c,D/d,E/e}
        \draw[->] ($(\L.south)+(0,-2pt)$) -- (\l.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd do `\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.append style={font=$\vphantom{^{0}}$, outer sep=.15em}}`.

Comment: You're right, I did not look for the best way to fix this.

Comment: thank you very much. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @mohamedadibabdelmoumene You can accept the answer if it suits you, so that other helpers know that you found what you were looking for. Or you could tell us what you still want specifically, if this answer is not good enough.

Comment: hello, i am really sorry for the late, I am new, I just accepted the answers, and it really helped me a lot. thank you very much.  @SebGlav