# How can I draw these arrows to explain the operation?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm trying to replicate the figure below,can someone help me?
the latex code is below

```
Let $A$ and $B$ be rings, where $B$ is an $A$-module.
If
\[
(a\cdot x)\underset{B}{\cdot}(b\cdot y)=(a\underset{A}{\cdot} b)\cdot(x\underset{B}{\cdot} y),\, \forall a,b\in A\textrm{ and }x,y\in B
\]
then $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ is a ring homomorphism and the structure of $B$ as $A$-module via $\phi$ is the original structure of $B$ as $A$-module.
```

if I use underset it looks awful.

[[image]]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need help drawing these arrows explaining where the elements are being operated on.

Comment: similar to this image https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5787/cZEZi2.png

Comment: Those arrows are all over the place though, do you want them squiggly or straight or what? This is why I put we need more info. Your question, whilst lacking any code, doesn't make it clear

Comment: They're badly made because I made them by hand.
The arrow can go either way, I just want to draw an arrow to explain the operation.

Comment: I've edited and added the code

Comment: One easy solution is to use the `tikzmark` library. You can find many examples here. [Here's one of them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688606/swarrow-in-linear-equations/688614#688614). But please first, edit your question with a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: tikzmark on equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\tmn}{\tikzmarknode}

\begin{document}
    \[
    (a\tmn{A}{\cdot} x)\underset{B}{\cdot}(b\tmn{B}{\cdot} y)=(a\underset{A}{\cdot} b)\tmn{C}{\cdot}(x\underset{B}{\cdot} y),\, \forall a,b\in A\textrm{ and }x,y\in B
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every path/.style={->}]
        \draw (A) --++ (0,-1) node[below] {Comment 1};
        \draw (B) --++ (0,-2) node[below] {Comment 2};
        \draw (C) --++ (0,-1) node[below] {Comment 3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As for the decoration (if it's really needed), you may fond by yourself what pleases you the most. Please note that you'll have to compile at least twice to get the final result with `tikzmark`.